# Logistic Regression inversely proportional correlation

Tags: regression, logistic, correlation, feature-selection, multicollinearity

This is more of a clarification question than anything else, but I am familiar that when dealing with regression algorithms it is useful to eliminate features that are highly correlated. I have been reading that this stays true for both highly +/- features. In a data science interview question video I saw a few months back asked a question on inversely correlated features and I believe the answer was that if two features are inversely proportional then they can both be fed into a logit model. Is this true?

Comment: Do you mean that $r_{XY} = -0.9?$

Comment: Yes exactly. @Dave

Comment: Did you or the interviewer (or answer key) say that both features can be fed into the model? // Why eliminate correlated features, even when the correlation is positive?

Comment: The question was asked by the interviewer and the interviewee answered with both features can be left to which the interviewer said was correct. Feeding features that are highly correlated into my logit model in SAS causes the convergence criteria to fail which states that the model coefficients cannot be trusted. @Dave

Comment: That's a problem with the algorithm, not the statistical procedure.